# How to remove the grey background from a facet_grid() (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have the following plot:

[image]

obtained by executing:

```
ggplot() + 
  stat_summary( data = test_data1, aes(x=x, y=(1-value) , colour = as.factor(1) , lty = as.factor(1) ) , fun.y=mean, geom="line" ,  size=1 ) +
  stat_summary( data = test_data1, aes(x=x, y=(1-value) , colour = as.factor(1), shape=as.factor(1) ) , fun.y=mean, geom="point" ,  size=3, pch=21, fill="white" ) +
  stat_summary( data = test_data2, aes(x=x, y=(1-value) , colour = as.factor(2), lty = as.factor(2) ) , fun.y=mean, geom="line", size=1 ) +
  stat_summary( data = test_data2, aes(x=x, y=(1-value) , colour = as.factor(2), shape=as.factor(2)) , fun.y=mean, geom="point", size=3, pch=21, fill="white" ) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14, base_family = "Palatino") + 
  theme(legend.key = element_blank() ) +
  expand_limits(x=c(0), y=c(0)) +
  facet_grid(distance ~ . )
```

How do I get rid of the grey background appearing behind `100` and `200`.

I would like that to be white, without changing the rest of the theme I am using at the moment.

Comment: Thanks! What should I do with this post? Delete it?

Answer (score 7):

After googling a bit more I found [this post](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_%28ggplot2%29/), which explains different manipulations that can be applied to `facet`.

In turns out my question can be solved by doing:

```
theme(legend.key = element_blank(), strip.background = element_rect(colour="red", fill="#CCCCFF") )
```

Using `strip.background = element_rect(colour="red", fill="#CCCCFF")` inside `theme()` does the work.